# ASP.NET gzip script and CSS on Global.asax

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, css, gzip

I am implementing this library in my application, *[GZip compress your website's HTML/CSS/Script in code](http://www.dominicpettifer.co.uk/Blog/17/gzip-compress-your-websites-html-css-script-in-code)*.

**It Works very well** if I run the site in Visual Studio, **but** when I compile my site and publish in IIS it only gzip ASPX files, not CSS or JavaScript files.

Is there a better way for implementing JavaScript and CSS gzip in C# corresponding to Visual Studio 2005 (changing the IIS is not an option as it has to be in the code).

Comment: What version of IIS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to create an HttpHandler for processing it:

```
namespace com.waynehartman.util.web.handlers
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://waynehartman.com/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    public class HttpCompressor : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            // Code for compressing the file and writing it to the HttpResponse
        }
        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return true; }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you need to add a handler mapping in your web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpHandlers>
            <add verb="*" path="*.css" 
                type="com.waynehartman.util.web.handlers.HttpCompressor, WayneHartmanUtilitiesLibrary"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*.js" 
                type="com.waynehartman.util.web.handlers.HttpCompressor, WayneHartmanUtilitiesLibrary"/>
        </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: and FullyQualified.Class and LibraryName will be?

Comment: as far as i know HttpHandlers is to combine multiple files in one, or something like this.

Comment: @jmpena HttpHandlers are for creating any customized handling of an http request or response.  They are designed to allow you to do exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: ok ill try your solution, but just one question (im a win32 dev), the code u put its a webservice or can be a class in my website ?

Comment: @jmpena [WebService] tags appear there by default when you create a new Generic Handler through Visual Studio.  I'm not sure what the side affects would be by removing them, by they are not hurting you by being there.  Try to think of a http handler as a rudimentary and nonspecializing aspx page.  Instead of .NET doing all the handling for a page request for you, you have complete control over what the request/response is.